# Included function not available later in scope

Tags: c++, c

I'm sorry for having to ask this but I'm stumped. I imagine it's just a simple misunderstanding of how C/C++ includes work. Here's what I have in my main file:

```
#include "application.h"
#include "flashHelper.h"
#include <ePaper.h>
...
void setup()
{
    SparkFlash_loadImage(image_270, sizeof(image_270), 0);
    ...
    EPAPER.image_flash();
}
```

I have recently moved some functions into flashHelper.cpp and flashHelper.h

flashHelper.h

```
#ifndef FLASHHELPER_H
#define FLASHHELPER_H

int SparkFlash_read(int address);
int SparkFlash_write(int address, uint16_t value);
void SparkFlash_erase(int address, int bytesToErase);
bool SparkFlash_writeB(const uint8_t* buffer, int numByteToWrite, int extFlashOffset);
bool SparkFlash_checkB(const uint8_t* buffer, int numByteToCheck, int extFlashOffset);
bool SparkFlash_loadImage(const uint8_t* buffer, int bufferSize, int flashOffset);

#endif  /* FLASHHELPER_H */
```

and obviously flashHelper.cpp has the actual function defined:

```
#include "flashHelper.h"

bool SparkFlash_loadImage(const uint8_t* buffer, int bufferSize, int flashOffset)
{
    ...
}

bool SparkFlash_checkB(const uint8_t* buffer, int numByteToCheck, int extFlashOffset)
{
...
}

bool SparkFlash_writeB(const uint8_t* buffer, int numByteToWrite, volatile int extFlashOffset)
{
...
}

void SparkFlash_erase(int address, int bytesToErase)
{
    ...   
}

int SparkFlash_read(int address)
{
  ...
}

int SparkFlash_write(int address, uint16_t value)
{
  ...
}
```

When I compile I get the following error: `../applications/e-paper/EPD.cpp:751:71: error: 'SparkFlash_read' was not declared in this scope` which, to me, means that the functions called by EPAPER.image_flash() do not have access/sight of the functions included in flashHelper.h. Any idea why? When I add the flashHelper.h definitions to application.h and then add the actual functions to my main file (application.cpp) it compiles without protest.

For those interested. The function/line/call which causes the error looks like:

```
void EPD_Class::line(uint16_t line, int extFlashAddress, uint8_t fixed_value, bool read_progmem, EPD_stage stage) 
{
    ...
    extFlashData = SparkFlash_read(extFlashAddress + i - 1);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Show us the line of code where the error occurred, i.e. the place you call `SparkFlash_read`. The complete compiler error message will also be helpful.

Comment: You do not provide enough information. You should create http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Did you recompile flashHelper.cpp after you made the changes to it and the header file? If not, the linker won't be able to find it.

Comment: @alpha.wolf: That's not a linker error.

Comment: @BillLynch, you're right. I read through the description too fast and assumed it said one thing when it said another.

Comment: I went ahead and tried to add the information y'all wanted

Comment: @harrisonhjones: You haven't provided a set of code that we can compile on our own machines.

Comment: Does EPD.cpp have the line `#include "flashHelper.h"` in it?

Comment: That is true. The build environment is fairly complex. I was hoping my problem was more of a "oh dummy you forgot to do X". It compiles when the functions and definitions are in application.cpp and application.h respectively but fails when moved to flashHelper.cpp and flashHelper.h respectively so I assumed I did not #include correctly.

Comment: @BillLynch, it does not. It is only in the main .cpp file

Comment: Check you haven't used the same id for your include guard in two different .h files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the top of `EPD.cpp`, add the line:

```
#include "flashHelper.h"
```

Comment: And, depending on where `flashHelper.h` is, he may need to tell the compiler where to find it (.i.e `-I/path/to/flashHelper.h` for `g++`)

Comment: Thanks @BillLynch. I figured it was a simple mistake of mine. Thanks everyone else too for the help